# ¿Como puedo sumar objetos repetidos de un array en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Tengo varios objetos en mi array llamado **miCarrito**

```
const miCarrito = [
  {
    "id_producto": 2,
    "nombre": "Bombilla individual GU10",
    "cantidad": 1,
    "precio": 20
  },
  {
    "id_producto": 3,
    "nombre": "Bombilla individual GU10",
    "cantidad": 1,
    "precio": 20
  },
  {
    "id_producto": 2,
    "nombre": "Bombilla individual GU10",
    "cantidad": 1,
    "precio": 20
  }
]
```

Como se puede observar hay un id dentro de los objetos que esta repetido **("id_producto":2)**, mi pregunta es ¿Como puedo sumar ese objeto para que la **cantidad** se modifique a  **2** ya que vendria siendo el mismo producto...
Gracias de antemano

Comment: Deberías mostrar que has intentando hasta el momento, no solamente el arreglo que necesitas tratar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo lo resolvería con un [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) de la siguiente manera:

1. Primero inicializaría el valor que el reduce va a devolver en un arreglo vacío
2. Luego comprobaría si el elemento ya existe en el acumulador.

   1. **Si no existe**, simplemente devuelvo un nuevo arreglo, con los elementos previos que hayan en el arreglo y el valor actual de la iteración
   2. **Si existe**, itero el acumulador con [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) para devolver un nuevo arreglo, vuelvo y compruebo que el objeto exista, si existe le sumo la cantidad actual de la iteración del map con la cantidad actual de la iteración del reduce, si no existe simplemente devuelvo el valor actual de la iteración dentro del map.

```js
let miCarrito = [{
    id_producto: 2,
    nombre: 'Bombilla individual GU10',
    cantidad: 1,
    precio: 20
  },
  {
    id_producto: 3,
    nombre: 'Bombilla individual GU10',
    cantidad: 1,
    precio: 20
  },
  {
    id_producto: 4,
    nombre: 'Bombilla individual GU10',
    cantidad: 10,
    precio: 20
  },
  {
    id_producto: 2,
    nombre: 'Bombilla individual GU10',
    cantidad: 1,
    precio: 20
  },
  {
    id_producto: 2,
    nombre: 'Bombilla individual GU10',
    cantidad: 5,
    precio: 20
  }
];

const miCarritoSinDuplicados = miCarrito.reduce((acumulador, valorActual) => {
  const elementoYaExiste = acumulador.find(elemento => elemento.id_producto === valorActual.id_producto);
  if (elementoYaExiste) {
    return acumulador.map((elemento) => {
      if (elemento.id_producto === valorActual.id_producto) {
        return {
          ...elemento,
          cantidad: elemento.cantidad + valorActual.cantidad
        }
      }

      return elemento;
    });
  }

  return [...acumulador, valorActual];
}, []);

console.log(miCarritoSinDuplicados);
```

Comment: me a funcionado a la perfección

Answer (score 0):

Recorres el array buscando el mismo id y colocas una bandera que te avise cuando lo encuentra. Si encuentra la coincidencia suma en uno la cantidad, de lo contrario sigue.
Cuando termina de recorrer el array la bander le indica si agrega o no un nuevo elemento.

```
 function Agregar(producto)
  {
    let repetido=false;

    for(let i=0; i< miCarrito.lenght; i++)
    {
      if(miCarrito[i].id==producto.id)
      {
        miCarrito[i].cantidad++
        repetido=true;
      }
    }
    if(repetido == false)
    {
      miCarrito.push(producto);
    }
  }
```